# MySQL Timestamp INSERT okay but sometimes fails

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, insert

So I've got a `bootstrap 3` form and there are a `clockpicker` and a `datepicker` plugins in it. I get all the data through PHP and try to insert into `MySQL` (currently in XAMPP). Sometimes the INSERT is okay, but sometimes one or both of the `Timestamp` fields in the DB are left at 0000....

Since I display the date like `17/09/2016` but I try to save it like `2016-17-09` in MySQL and I have to concatenate the text from the clockpicker to the text from the date picker, I do that:

```
    $startDate = $_POST['shiftStartDate'] . " " . $_POST['shiftStartTime'];
$startDateFormat = str_replace('/', '-', $startDate);
$date1 = date_create($startDateFormat);
$dateTime1 = date_format($date1, 'Y-d-m H:i:s');



$endDate = $_POST['shiftEndDate'] . " " . $_POST['shiftEndTime'];
$endDateFormat = str_replace('/', '-', $endDate);
$date2 = date_create($endDateFormat);
$dateTime2 = date_format($date2, 'Y-d-m H:i:s');
```

Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**:
When formatting, conform to MySQL's requirement of Y-m-d, NOT Y-d-m:

```
$dateTime2 = date_format($date2, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: why would you like to save it as `2016-17-19` instead of the latter, exactly?

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic Thats an interesting date you picked?? WHich calendar is that on

Comment: Most likely because it's a valid MySQL data format (YYYY-MM-DD). Anyway - this happens when the format is not a valid date format - so MySQL doesn't know how to handle it. Try echoing `$dateTime1` and `$dateTime2` before the insert, and make sure it is always in the format you expect. Also - there is no date like 2016-17-09 (only 12 months in the calendar :))

Comment: @RiggsFolly ahaha *09

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic hehhe thats the one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MYSQL expects the date format to be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS when you save it to the database in a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column datatype

You are trying to save it as YYYY-DD-MM. That will only work if the DD is less than 12 so that probably explains why it sometimes works and sometimes does not

So format your dates correctly to what MYSQL expects and all will be well.

I would also expect that you would be getting some odd results when you read back the dates that did save to the database.

Comment: Yes, that's the bug... I knew the formats need to match and that's why I'm doing formatting in the first place but for some reason I got confused and changed the order of D and M.... Thank you!